# How do I get Visual Studio Code to show python executed code only in debug window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

How do I get VSC to show python executed code only in debug window. Currently, it keeps showing in the terminal with a long ugly path before the result.

The Debug console shows "hello world" nicely but I'm doing a tutorial and I don't want the terminal automatically being the default to show the output with this long ugly path.

Any one know how to configure it to do this? I tried many configurations in launch.json to no avail.

[image]
[image]